# Custom R Package doesn't show Help documentation for functions but works locally

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I have created a simple package hosted on my private github.

It contains two simple functions which are documented.
If I run `Install and Restart` in Build tab, the package get installed correctly.
Once done, I can run `?my_fun` and see the documentation and type `my_fun` to see all code

If I install the same package using

```
devtools::install_github('yy/package',
                         upgrade = 'never',
                         dependencies = T,
                         auth_token = token)
```

The package is well installed and I can run `library(mypackage)`
I can run `my_fun` to see the function's code but if I run `?my_fun` I get
*No documentation for ‘my_fun’ in specified packages and libraries:*

How can I solve this?
I tried devtools::document and also tried to install from binary, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The names of the functions were too long. Once I reduced length, it worked...